# Brung vs Brought

Tags: vocabulary

I have heard *brung" in a musical in this sentence, "What has this madness **brung** us?" and I know that almost no dictionaries list *brung* as an existent word at all, but I've got an assumption: maybe *brung* can be used as the past simple and past participle of *to bring* when used figuratively? That is, when it doesn't really mean moving something somewhere.

Examples:

1. I won't ever lend you any money: you've **brung** me too much sadness in my life.

Or should it be *brought* in any case? That is:

2. I won't ever lend you any money: you've **brought** me too much sadness in my life.

If my assumption is right, it explains why *brung* was used in that musical, as *madness* cannot really "bring".

Comment: bring, brought, brought. brung is non-standard, regional and also marked as uneducated by some. This question belongs on ELL, not here.

Comment: Or perhaps the musical included "brung" for some other reason, e.g. as a pun or for rhyme. It's hard for us to tell with only the one sentence that you quoted. (That's why you should [provide more context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and [cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source)!)